# how to manage json data in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I called JSON data and got following output:

```
stdClass Object
(
[request] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Target] => Affiliate_Report
        [Format] => json
        [Service] => HasOffers
        [Version] => 3
        [Method] => getConversions
        [api_key] => my_key
        [NetworkId] => icubes
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => Offer.name
                [1] => Browser.display_name
                [2] => Stat.payout
                [3] => Stat.sale_amount
                [4] => Stat.status
                [5] => Stat.datetime
                [6] => Stat.ip
                [7] => Stat.ad_id
                [8] => Stat.affiliate_info1
            )

    )

[response] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => 1
        [httpStatus] => 200
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [page] => 1
                [current] => 100
                [count] => 75
                [pageCount] => 1
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Offer] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Myntra (CPS)
                                    )

                                [Browser] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [display_name] => Chrome
                                    )

                                [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [payout] => 150.00000
                                        [sale_amount] => 954.00000
                                        [status] => rejected
                                        [datetime] => 2014-03-31 19:49:50
                                        [ip] => 103.226.84.249
                                        [ad_id] => 102ecc5fe230883c195d8a0e84ef7f
                                        [affiliate_info1] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Offer] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Myntra (CPS)
                                    )

                                [Browser] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [display_name] => Firefox
                                    )

                                [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [payout] => 270.00000
                                        [sale_amount] => 545.00000
                                        [status] => approved
                                        [datetime] => 2014-04-18 12:00:20
                                        [ip] => 27.0.51.119
                                        [ad_id] => 10256740541d68b117955aa58529a6
                                        [affiliate_info1] => 
                                    )

                            )
```

I want to display that data in tabular form using table tag and also want to insert that data into a MySQL database.

But I dont understand the array format of data.

My code:

```
$result = file_get_contents($base);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo"<table>";
foreach($obj as $item) {
echo"
<tr>
<td>$item['Offer.name']</td>
<td>$item['Browser.display_name']</td>
<td>$item['Stat.payout']</td>
<td>$item['Stat.sale_amount']</td>
<td>$item['Stat.datetime']</td>
<td>$item['Stat.ip']</td>
</tr>
"; 
}
echo"</table>";
```

This code gives me a blank output.

---

i used following code and got output but some errors are still there.

```
$result = file_get_contents($base);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);
echo"<table border=1>";
$i = 0;
    foreach($obj['response'] as $item) {

    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
    {
        echo"
        <tr>
        <td>{$item['data'][$i]['Offer']['name']}</td>
        <td>{$item['data'][$i]['Stat']['payout']}</td>
        <td>{$item['data'][$i]['Stat']['sale_amount']}</td>
        <td>{$item['data'][$i]['Stat']['status']}</td>
        <td>{$item['data'][$i]['Stat']['datetime']}</td>
        <td>{$item['data'][$i]['Stat']['ip']}</td>
        </tr>
        "; 
    }

    }
echo"</table>";
```

my output:

[image]

why upper rows are displaying blank values when there is no blank data is present?

and what are those errors?

Comment: Please, post the result of `var_dump($obj)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. It's difficult to see exactly the results you're expecting, the values of the objects being returned look like they are objects of the original json themselves and without any useful data. However, to clarify for you:

You're returning the `json_decode()` results as an object and trying to access it as an array.
To return an associative array you need to add the 'assoc' parameter to the function, to read:

```
json_decode($result, true)
```

and you were trying to eco out the value directly from the associative array, you need to access it via the key, which will give you the value to read:

```
$result = file_get_contents($base);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);
echo"<table>";
foreach($obj['request'] as $item) {
echo"
<tr>
<td>{$item['fields'][0]}</td>
<td>{$item['fields'][1]}</td>
<td>{$item['fields'][2]}</td>
<td>{$item['fields'][3]}</td>
<td>{$item['fields'][4]}</td>
<td>{$item['fields'][5]}</td>
</tr>
"; 
}
echo"</table>";
```

Also, I've added the curly brackets inside the string to escape the variable expressions.

Comment: i tried your code but it gives me an error 

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array ($item['fields'][0])

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting objects in your response, first try `json_decode($result->request)` and generally don't use `[ ]` as you normally would as if your result was array

EDIT: Try outputting the response like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($your-variable-here);
echo '</pre>';
```

Then let me know of the output

Comment: can't get it.. i want to display the data generated by json in tabular form but i can't understand the structure of array and getting error of Undefined index: Offer.name

Comment: the output which i mention in my question is the output of print_r(json_decode($result))